# How to quit while activities are in stack (to avoid redrawing during logout/back)?

Tags: android, android-activity

## Problem

I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage the activity stack to gracefully handle both logging out and quitting. None of the similar questions seem to address this.

**I want to keep LoginActivity on the activity stack to avoid showing a blank screen when the user logs out or hits back. Doing so messes up quitting.**

* *Quitting = hitting my "Quit" menu item, which sends a broadcast, calls finish() or finishAndRemoveTask(), then System.exit(0)*

---

## Situation

*If it's the first time the user's logged in on this device, they follow Flow 1*

**Flow 1:**
   LoginActivity > TermsActivity > PrivacyActivity > MainActivity

**Flow 2:**
   LoginActivity > MainActivity

---

- In Flow 1, PrivacyActivity clears the activity stack when it starts MainActivity

  ✔   *Quitting works properly*

  ✖   *Logging out shows a briefly blank screen as it needs to redraw*
- In Flow 2, LoginActivity doesn't call finish(), so it remains on the activity stack

  ✔   *Logging out looks smooth, as LoginActivity doesn't need to be redrawn*

  ✖   *Quitting doesn't work - when MainActivity finishes, LoginActivity is displayed. Even if I use System.exit(0), the app is minimized, not truly closed. When the user hits the Overview button, the app is still there and can be reopened (to LoginActivity).*

---

## Approaches

Unsatisfactory suggested answers to other questions:

- Always call finish() when starting the next activity
- Add android:noHistory="true" to activities in the manifest

I don't like these because:

- This results in a (briefly) blank LoginActivity when the user logs out of MainActivity
- In Flow 1, the first 3 activities should all be "backable" - this approach results in (briefly) blank screens when hitting back

---

Another suggested approach is to use startActivityForResult() while moving forwards and then react to that in onActivityResult() while moving backwards

- onActivityResult() is called right before onResume(), but there's a bunch of stuff that happens in LoginActivity's onCreate() and onStart()

  - I'd like MainActivity's quit transition to be the standard "shrink to middle" one
  - I'm worried that quitting would result in a transition to LoginActivity, a (short but not unnoticeable) wait/flash of blank gray, then an exit
  - More activities will be added later - this could result in having to traverse a chain of activities just to quit
  - If TermsActivity and PrivacyActivity are removed from the stack when MainActivity is started, I'm not sure if this would result in LoginActvity.onActivityResult() being called, since it's PrivacyActivity that starts MainActivity.

---

## Question

**How can I keep activities on the stack (in case the user hits back or logs out), but clear the stack while quitting?**

Comment: Just so we're clear, are you calling "quitting" when the user presses Home button? Or actually killing the app (by swiping it away from the recents)? Or a logic implemented in code?

Comment: I should've been more specific: I have a "Quit" menu item that [1] sends a broadcast [2] calls finish() or finishAndRemoveTask() depending on API version [3] calls System.exit(0)

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment regarding "quitting", I would have an approach that encapsulates activities in Tasks.

Task 1 would be (0)
 LoginActivity > TermsActivity > PrivacyActivity
Task 2 would start at (0)
  MainActivity

This way :
 - Pressing back inside Task1 would navigate as expected (and as you already have)
 - Pressing back from MainActivity would close the app (as technically I don't expect to be logged out when pressing back).

The only logic you'd have to implement is :
  - Quit would clear stack trace (as you have)
  - Logout would launch LoginActivity and kill MainActivity(1).

(0) and (1) : Add the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to your Intent
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem. I've tried 1 task ([LA, MA]), 2 tasks ([LA, TA, PA], [MA]) and 3 ([LA], [TA, PA], [MA]). The behavior appears to be the same. Quit only works properly if LA calls finish(), but this results in a blank screen during logout. If LA doesn't call finish(), logging out is nice, but quitting leaves the app visible in Overview since LA hasn't been finished. My quit action doesn't really clear the activity stack, which seems to be the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is implement fragments, it will be easier to handle the stack.

Comment: You're probably right. I've been putting off converting the app to use fragments because I expect it'll take a fair amount of time and the higher-ups have been pushing for the v1.0 release soon, so I think I'm going to have to finish() LoginActivity every time, and just accept the blank gray screen for now.